# Importing the entries to be filled in the UI, from a file, in qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I created a UI in qt4. Now I should be giving an option to the user to fill the entries in the UI, from an existing file on system,which the user can browse for.
Now, Iam able to set the line edit entries in my UI from the file that the user specifies but I am not able to set the highlighted text in the comboboxes to what the file has. This might be very vague, Iam not able to explain this properly.Here is the code snippet i used:

```
//browsing for the file
path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
    this,
    "Choose a file to import data from",
    QString::null);

QFileInfo fi(path);
ui->lineEdit_21->setText( path );

//opening the file specified by user, for reading
name = fi.fileName();
dir = fi.path();
QDir::setCurrent(dir);
QFile read(name);
QString str;

     if (!read.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         return;

     QTextStream in(&read);
     while (!in.atEnd())
     {
         QString line = in.readLine();
         //filling the UI from the file
         if(line.contains("AP SSID :", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
         {
             str = line.section(':', 1, 1);
             ui -> lineEdit->setText(str);
         }
     }
```

This works fine but now how do I change the selected entry in a combobox, in accordance with the file?

```
if(line.contains("FREQUENCY :", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
         {
             str = line.section(':', 1, 1);
             ui -> comboBox_2->setEditText(str);
         }
```

I tried this but this is not working. My combobox_2 has two frequencies 2.4GHz and 5GHz. If the user selected file has 2.4GHz then I want the combobox to update itself such that 2.4GHz entry is highlighted. Hope I have made my point. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [findText](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcombobox.html#findText) function in order to get the index of the given text in the combobox.

```
int frequencyIndex = ui->comboBox_2->findText(str);

if (frequnecyIndex != -1)
   ui->comboBox_2->setCurrentIndex(frequencyIndex);
```